# Wav file containing only silence not playing (made through C)

Tags: c, algorithm, audio, wav

My actual project is more involved, but I believe if I can troubleshoot this simpler code, I will be able to get my project fully working. The header info and the number of bytes that I have written, my expectaions, and information printed to the screen make sense, but upon opening the wav file, an error is met and shown. From the 45th byte only short int zeroes are written, meaning the entire wav file is only silence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{   int i;
   typedef struct h{
   char ChunkID[4];             /*RIFF*/
   unsigned int ChunkSize;
   char format[4];         /*WAVE*/
   char SubChunk1ID[4];              /*fmt*/
   unsigned int SubChunk1Size;
   unsigned short int AudioFormat;
   unsigned short int NumChannels;
   unsigned int SampleRate;
   unsigned int ByteRate;
   short int BlockAlign;
   short int BitsPerSample;
   char SubChunk2ID[4];
   unsigned int SubChunk2Size;
   }rtz;
   /*start of filling out the information we know*/
        rtz HeaderOut;
            HeaderOut.SampleRate = 44100;
            HeaderOut.NumChannels = 1;
            HeaderOut.BitsPerSample = 16;
            strcpy(HeaderOut.ChunkID,"RIFF");
            strcpy(HeaderOut.format,"WAVE");
            strcpy(HeaderOut.SubChunk1ID,"fmt");
            strcpy(HeaderOut.SubChunk2ID,"data");
            HeaderOut.AudioFormat = 1;
            HeaderOut.ChunkSize = 1411236;
            HeaderOut.SubChunk2Size = 1411200;
HeaderOut.SubChunk1Size = 16;
HeaderOut.ByteRate = HeaderOut.SampleRate*HeaderOut.NumChannels*HeaderOut.BitsPerSample/8;
HeaderOut.BlockAlign = HeaderOut.NumChannels*HeaderOut.BitsPerSample/8;
printf("ChunkID       = RIFF        %d bytes\n", sizeof(HeaderOut.ChunkID));
printf("Chunksize     = %d     %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.ChunkSize,sizeof(HeaderOut.ChunkSize));
printf("format        = WAVE        %d bytes\n",sizeof(HeaderOut.format));
printf("SubChunk1ID   = %s         %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.SubChunk1ID,sizeof(HeaderOut.SubChunk1ID));
printf("SubChunkSize  = %d          %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.SubChunk1Size,sizeof(HeaderOut.SubChunk1Size));
printf("AudioFormat   = %d           %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.AudioFormat,sizeof(HeaderOut.AudioFormat)); /* AUDIOFORMAT CHANGES*/
printf("NumChannels   = %d           %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.NumChannels,sizeof(HeaderOut.NumChannels));
printf("SampleRate    = %d       %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.SampleRate,sizeof(HeaderOut.SampleRate));
printf("ByteRate      = %d       %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.ByteRate,sizeof(HeaderOut.ByteRate));
printf("BlockAlign    = %d           %d bytes\n",HeaderOut.BlockAlign,sizeof(HeaderOut.BlockAlign));
printf("BitsPerSample = %d          %d bytes\n", HeaderOut.BitsPerSample,sizeof(HeaderOut.BitsPerSample));
printf("SubChunk2ID   = data        %d bytes\n",sizeof(HeaderOut.SubChunk2ID));
printf("SubChunk2Size = %d     %d bytes\n\n",HeaderOut.SubChunk2Size,sizeof(HeaderOut.SubChunk2Size));
printf("Size of HeaderOut = %d bytes\n", sizeof(HeaderOut));
printf("\n");
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("experiment.wav","wb");
if(fp == NULL){printf("File did not open successfully.\n");
}else{
            fwrite(&HeaderOut,44,1,fp);
printf("File successfully opened.\n");
short int silence[14700];
    for (i = 0; i<14700 ; i++){
        silence[i] = 0;
    }
for (i = 0 ; i<48; i++){
         fwrite(silence, sizeof( short int), 14700,fp);
}
fclose(fp);
}/*end of else statement*/
}/*end of MAIN */
```

Comment: The "fmt " chunk identifier is supposed to be 4 bytes long, padded with a space, but you write only 3 characters, so maybe you get a junk byte and the chunk is not recognised.

Comment: Wow you are absolutely correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with this code. Using `strcpy` to copy `"RIFF"` will also copy a null character (`'\0'`) at the end (out-of-bound). Same with `"WAVE"`. But you're not seeing the effects since you're sequentially writing them, so null bytes are overwritten. However, that's a bug lurking around the corner. I would set the bytes one-by-one. I would also use a well tested library to handle `.wav` files, since you mentioned your project is more involved. Consider using [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) to remove unneeded complexity from your project.